# ¿Como puedo automatizar la carga de imagenes en matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente código, que me imprime ordenadamente la visualización de los archivos en una carpeta en el terminal, necesito abrirlos estos secuencialemente usando matplotlib; o sea abro el primero, lo cierro, luego el segundo, lo cierro, luego el tercero y así hasta abrir el ultimo archivo que hay en la carpeta. Mi código para obtener los archivos a mostrar es:

```
import os, sys

path = '    '
total = 0

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):

    for file in f:

        if ".fits" in file:
            f.sort()
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

            total +=1

for i,f in enumerate(files):
    print("{} {}".format(i,f))

print(total)
```

Lo necesito para poder abrir archivos fits, este el script para abrirlos con matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import os,sys,string
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from astropy.io import fits

image_file = 'PLO-2007.fits'
fits.info(image_file)
image_data = fits.getdata(image_file, ext=0)


hdul = fits.open(image_file)
#['COL-1']



timevlf =image_data[:,0]
phase =image_data[:,2]


plt.figure()
plt.plot(timevlf, phase,'-', linewidth=1, color='red')
plt.xlabel('Time [UT]')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: No entiendo el objetivo, necesitas visualizar una lista de archivos.. secuencialmente cada N tiempo, que espere que el usuario cierre el archivo.? en que caso procederá a mostrar el siguiente archivo.?

Comment: @JhoubertRincon, es que tengo una carpeta con archivos fits, el código de arriba ya me reconoce estos archivos en la carpeta, lo que quiero es abrir uno por uno de estos archivos cada cierto tiempo

Comment: @JhoubertRincon necestio abrir un archivo, visualizarlo y luego cerrarlo, asi secuencialmente hasta terminar con el ultimo archivo de la carpeta.

Comment: Entiendo, pero quien cierra el archivo.? tu.? el script.? con qué programa lo abres.?

Comment: @JhoubertRincon, yo soy el que abre y cierra el archivo solo quiero que el programa lo haga de forma automática.

Comment: @JhoubertRincon, voy a editar la pregunta para colocar mas información

Comment: Con que programa se abre el archivo?

Comment: @JhoubertRincon, lo abro con un script mismo de python

Comment: @JhoubertRincon ya esta editado

Comment: @the_striker, fijate lo importante que son los detalles, esta es la segúnda pregunta que haces respecto a este tema (cosa que no deberías hacer). de haber mencionado que estas usando matplotlib, seguramente ya te habrían dado la respuesta.

Comment: @JhoubertRincon, precisamente por eso hago la pregunta, por que no encuentro la respuesta.

Comment: @the_striker lo entiendo, realmente necesitas resolver tu problema, pero cuando eso pasa intenta editar tu pregunta y el sitio te pone de primero en la lista nuevamente y si es posible ofrece recompensa.

Comment: @podrias echarme una mano?

Comment: Si, pero no estoy en el computador, en un rato te echo una mano, lo único es que no estoy seguro de que formato es el archivo: PLO-2007.fits

Comment: Alli va un path, solo es un archivo de prueba.

Comment: ¿Existe una forma de poder abrir esos archivos uno por uno de forma automática?

Comment: @the_striker Volver a hacer la pregunta no mejorará las respuestas que te den. Deberías haber hecho lo que te aconseja JhoubertRincon para mejorar la pregunta y el interés por ella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que tienes que hacer es evitar que el script se detenga al hacer el show para esperar el tiempo que creas necesario para cerrar y seguir con la sigueinte imagen, uniendo tus cos códigos quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import numpy as np
import os,sys,string
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from astropy.io import fits



path = '/PLO-2010'
total = 0

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if ".fits" in file:
            f.sort()
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
            total +=1

for i,f in enumerate(files):
    print("{} {}".format(i,f))
    image_file = f
    fits.info(image_file)
    image_data = fits.getdata(image_file, ext=0)


    hdul = fits.open(image_file)
#['COL-1']

    timevlf =image_data[:,0]
    phase =image_data[:,2]


    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(timevlf, phase,'-', linewidth=1, color='red')
    plt.xlabel('Time [UT]')
    plt.grid()

    plt.show(block=False) #Evito que el form bloquee el script.
    plt.pause(3) #Espero 3 segundos.
    plt.close() #Cierro el plot

print("done")
print(total)
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!